# How to pass BluetoothGatt and Characteristic to AsyncTask in Android?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, bluetooth-lowenergy

I want to use `AsyncTask` to implement `mGatt.writeCharacteristic`.

At first , I try to pass `mBluetoothGatt` and `BluetoothGattCharacteristic` to `AsyncTask` like the following code.

```
private static BluetoothGatt mBluetoothGatt;
BluetoothGattCharacteristic HueCharacteristic;

new WriteCharacteristic().execute(mBluetoothGatt , HueCharacteristic);
private class WriteCharacteristic extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {

        BluetoothGatt gatt = params[0];
        BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic = params[1]; 
        return null;
    }
    // onPostExecute displays the results of the AsyncTask.
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    }
}
```

But I don't know how to verify the param at `AsyncTask<String, Void, String>`. I have try `AsyncTask<BluetoothGatt, Void, String>` , but it has error.

**How to pass `BluetoothGatt` and `Characteristic` to `AsyncTask` in `Android` ?**

Comment: Please show the error you are getting with AsyncTask<BluetoothGatt, Void, String> because that is the better way to use this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write your own constructor in your AsyncTask. Like this:

```
private class WriteCharacteristic extends AsyncTask<String, Void,String> {
public WriteCharacteristic(String a, int b) {
    //do something with the variables. Save them, whatever
}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
    return null;
}
// onPostExecute displays the results of the AsyncTask.
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
}
}
```

And you can call it this way:

```
new WriteCharacteristic("a",1).execute();
```

Comment: this is not how to use an AsyncTask .. the AsyncTask allready have parameter types AsyncTask<IntputType, ProgressType, OutputType>.. you are not using the AsyncTask propperly cause it expects a String input and it will give a string out but you are not using them at all this makes no sense.

Comment: I'm presenting a alternative approach that works too.

Answer (score 0):

AsyncTasks not too great to use since on config change they go away butt here is what you can do

```
private BluetoothGatt mBluetoothGatt;
BluetoothGattCharacteristic HueCharacteristic;

public MyDataObject {
    public MyDataObject(BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothGattCharacteristic, ch) {
         this.gatt = gatt; this.ch = ch;
    public BluetoothGatt gatt;
    public BluetoothGattCharacteristic ch;
}


new WriteCharacteristic().execute(new MyDataObject(mBluetoothGatt, HueCharacteristic));
private class WriteCharacteristic extends AsyncTask<MyDataObject , Void, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(MyDataObject... data) {

        return null;
    }
    // onPostExecute displays the results of the AsyncTask.
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    }
}
```